# Error installing Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio/MS SQL Server 2014/MS SQL Server Data Tools in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssms, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-2015

I am facing the below errors when trying to install any type of MS SQL Server on Windows 10 operating system. There seem to be a common problem/error in all of the cases (i.e. **An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.CRT,version="8.0.50727.4027",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"**) for which I could not find any workable solution in earlier related posts or other sites (quora, microsoft support etc). This is similar to iTunes installation error but the workaround for that particular solution did not solve my problem. Screenshots provided in the following arrangement:

1. MS SQL Server Management Studio 2016
   [image: Screenshot for error_SQL Management Studio]
2. MS Visual Studio 2015
   [image: Screenshot for error_Visual Studio 2014]

Comment: Have you tried installing the [Visual C++ redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5555)?

Comment: yes but no luck...same error

Comment: Go to `C:\Windows\Installer` and search for `*.msi`, then add the `Comments` column to the Explorer window and find the file for  `Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable`, right click and Repair, then if necessary point it to your downloaded `vcredist_x86.exe` when prompted to do so.

Comment: Hi,
Getting this error as below (screenshot shared via google drive link):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B857YPlbNCkJZE15WmZkbkxBWmM

It will only accept *.msi packages and not *.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, I have been able to solve the issue. **THANKS 3N1GM4!! You did point me to the right direction!** Fiddling a bit here and there solved the issue. Listing down the steps as reference to other users facing the same:

1. Quoting 3N1GM4: "Go to C:\Windows\Installer and search for *.msi, then add the Comments column to the Explorer window and find the file for Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable"
2. Right click and uninstall
3. Download vcredist_x86.exe
4. Extract content of vcredist_x86.exe using command prompt, which will result to the VCREDI~3.EXE being extracted. Ref: (http://www.itninja.com/software/microsoft/visual-c-2005-redistributable/8-1662)
5. Once again, extract VCREDI~3.EXE following the steps in above link, which will result to i) vcredis1.cab and ii) vcredist.msi being extracted.
6. Now, run and install vcredist.msi

Note: Not sure if steps 5 & 6 were redundant but I went through with them anyway. Installing vcredist_x86 directly after step 3 may also solve the problem.

**Once again, I would like to thank 3N1GM4 for this ingenuity!**